# How can i define a baseclass for SwiftRealm object?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I define a base model class from Object class, it creates a new table. How can I define a master model class which has some common properties?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to do this, as from the Realm documentation:

> The following is not possible:
>
> - Casting between polymorphic classes (ie, subclass to subclass,
>     subclass to parent, parent to subclass, etc.).
> - Querying on multiple
>     classes simultaneously.
> - Multi-class containers (List and Results).
>
> Adding this functionality to Realm is on the roadmap, and for the time
>   being, we’ve provided some code samples for working around some of the
>   more common patterns.

Since you can't cast from a concrete class to your master class, it may restrict you too much. If you provide more details about what you want to achieve, people may be able to help in other ways.